# Error while bitbake to create a ROS package for beaglebone

Tags: ros, bitbake

I am trying to compile the hello world program of ROS tutorials to beaglebone black using bitbake. I am using an Ubuntu PC and have setup the workspace as mentioned in the user manual provided in [vmayoral github link](https://github.com/vmayoral/diving-meta-ros)
I have modified the local.conf file in the /build/conf folder and contents look like this

```
DL_DIR = "${OEBASE}/sources"
BBFILES = "${OEBASE}/openembedded/recipes/*/*.bb" 
ASSUME_PROVIDED += "help2man-native"
PREFERRED_PROVIDERS = "virtual/qte:qte virtual/libqpe:libqpe-opie"
PREFERRED_PROVIDERS += " virtual/libsdl:libsdl-x11"
PREFERRED_PROVIDERS += " virtual/${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc-initial:gcc-cross-initial"
PREFERRED_PROVIDERS += " virtual/${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc-intermediate:gcc-cross-intermediate"
PREFERRED_PROVIDERS += " virtual/${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc:gcc-cross"
PREFERRED_PROVIDERS += " virtual/${TARGET_PREFIX}g++:gcc-cross"
MACHINE = "beaglebone"
DISTRO = "angstrom-2008.1"
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "jffs2 tar"
BBINCLUDELOGS = "yes"
```

The bitbake recipe as below

```
DESCRIPTION = "Beginner_tutorials, talker/listener ROS package"
SECTION = "devel"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM =     "file://package.xml;;beginline=16;endline=16;md5=05c8b019cf5b0834bc5e547a1 4f26ca3"
DEPENDS = "roscpp catkin rospy std-msgs"
RDEPENDS = "roscpp rospy std-msgs"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/vmayoral/beginner_tutorials.git"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
PV = "1.0.0+gitr${SRCPV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
inherit catkin
```

When I run `bitbake test.bb` from oe/build folder I get this following error

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):File /home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 175 in wrapped return func(fn, *args)File "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 185, in parse_config_filereturn bb.parse.handle(fn, data, include) File "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 107, in handle return h['handle'](fn, data, include)File "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/parse_py/ConfHandler.py", line 145, in handle feeder(lineno, s, abs_fn, statements) File  "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/parse_py/ConfHandler.py", line 182, in feederraise ParseError("unparsed line: '%s'" % s, fn, lineno);ParseError: ParseError at home/srijit/oe/openembedded/conf/bitbake.conf:377: unparsed line: 'IMAGE_EXTRA_SPACE = 10240' ERROR: Unable to parse conf/bitbake.conf: ParseError at /home/srijit/oe/openembedded/conf/bitbake.conf:377: unparsed line: 'IMAGE_EXTRA_SPACE = 10240'
```

I dont know what to do

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I did more search on google.. I found [here](http://logs.nslu2-linux.org/livelogs/oe/oe.20120705.txt) that we can't use the latest bitbake with openembedded-classic. So tried with bitbake 1.10 and this error went away.. But I have a new error now. It is

```
Unknown Event: <bb.event.NoProvider instance at 0x7f05e40ee248>
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'mobile-unit.bb'
Command execution failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 88, in     runAsyncCommand commandmethod(self.cmds_async, self, options)
File "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 174, in buildTargets command.cooker.buildTargets(pkgs_to_build, task)
File "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 782, in buildTargets
taskdata.add_provider(localdata, self.status, k)
File "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/taskdata.py", line 354, in add_provider
self.add_provider_internal(cfgData, dataCache, item)
File "/home/srijit/oe/bitbake/lib/bb/taskdata.py", line 383, in add_provider_internal
raise bb.providers.NoProvider(item)
NoProvider: mobile-unit.bb
```

Comment: If you have a new error (i.e. the problem isn't resolved), don't post it as an answer but better edit your question.

Comment: Avoid using openembedded-classic for new works, unless yo really have to. All development efforts for the latest number of years has gone to openembedded-core and meta-openembedded.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue.. thought it will be helpful for somebody else. I think the main issue was my immaturity in understanding the ROS meta-ros layer and how it work and that the overall (mis)direction in installing ROS in BBB. I was trying to compile the beagle-ros for the Angstrom distribution that came with BBB. That was the problem. 
Actually I downloaded the lates Angstrom distribution source in my Ubuntu PC and compiled for BBB as described [here](http://derekmolloy.ie/building-angstrom-for-beaglebone-from-source/). Few tweaks here and there

Then we have to flash that Angstrom distribution to an SD Card and boot BBB from that.

Then you follow the instructions here to compile the beagle-ros layer and ros packages using the same bitbake setup as you compiled for Angstrom as discussed [here](https://github.com/vmayoral/beagle-ros) and [here](http://www.mobilewill.us/2013/11/bbb-adventures-in-ros-cross-compiling.html)

Now copy the compiled ipk files to BBB and install it using opkg and now you can run them on BBB